# Invoke a method with generic argument

Tags: c#, generics

I have a generic class and I take its type as a parameter type e.g. `int` for a method in my class like below:

```
public class UnlimitedGenericArray<T>
{
 private void InsertItem(T item)
 {
  this.array[0] = item;
 }
}
```

Now, when I want to invoke the `InsertItem()`from a console application for example how can I know the argument's type at runtime?

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        UnlimitedGenericArray<int> oArray = new UnlimitedGenericArray<int>();
        while(true)
        {
         var userInput = Console.Readline();
         oArray.InsertItem(userInput);
        }
    }
```

I can write `InsertItem(object item)` instead and then cast in the method like below:

```
private void InsertItem(object item)
     {
      this.array[0] = (T)Convert.ChangeType(item, typeof(T));
     }
```

But this is probably not a good practice. I also need to know the type of argument at client so that I can parse there and then invoke the method. I am new to Generics so help me out here please.

Comment: Where are you trying to invoke the method?  Why do you need to invoke it?  `InsertItem(5)` will compile just fine.  `T` resolves to `int`.

Comment: What is the type of this.array?

Comment: @Amy I am trying to invoke the method from a console app inside `main()` and I am adding the class to my project. I need to invoke it because this is only way user can insert an item in an array. `InsertItem(5)` will compile fine but I am reading the user input `Console.Readline()` so if my `InsertItem` takes `int` as its argument type then it would say `cannot convert from string to int`.

Comment: @EricLippert `this.array` is generic array type inside the class I mentioned above `private T[] array = new T[0];` You probably figured it but I am trying to build a class that will use only arrays to store undetermined number of items of user defined type.

Comment: @Md.lbrahim: Then I don't understand the question. You have a method that takes a T, you have an array of T, so insert the item into the array. Why would you want to mess around with reflection? `this.array[0] = item;` should work just fine if the array is T[] and item is T.

Comment: You might consider obtaining the source code to the base class library -- search for "Microsoft Shared Source Initiative" -- and study how `List<T>` works.

Comment: @EricLippert `this.array[0] = item;` is what I am doing inside the class when user input is passed from the console app. But when I am sending the user input it is from `var userInput = Console.Readline()` which returns `string` so if my array was initialized as `int` or other type and I am doing something like `oArray.InsertItem(userInput)` then there would be an exception for not being able to convert from string to int. I cannot `cast` either because there is not way to know the type either and that is the problem.

Comment: Then use int.tryparse to convert the string to int.

Comment: @EricLippert How can I only use `int.Tryparse` when I want the user of the class to be able to initialize the class as any type e.g. `UnlimitedGenericArray<decimal>` or custom types `UnlimitedGenericArray<Product>`? Maybe I am approaching this incorrectly but that is why I posted here to get some suggestion on the situation. Maybe I can upload the whole solution for people here to look at?

Comment: So suppose the type argument is Product. What do you expect the user to type in so as to obtain an object representing a cheesecake or a washing machine?

Comment: @EricLippert I went through the source code of generic List as you suggested and I understand now that I have been looking at it the wrong way.Thanks again for your continuous help and suggestions. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You *don't* know the type in the body of the method. If you knew the type then you would not have used generics in the first place.

You might not want to use generics here. If you need to make a decision based on the type then your method is not *generic*.

Comment: " If you need to make a decision based on the type then your method is not generic." - classic...

Comment: Yes exactly. I don't know the type in the method body I also want user to have the flexibility to initialize any type of array.
So, I hope you understand what I am trying to do here. What changes would you suggest then?

Answer (score 0):

When you specify the generic parameter as int, you may as well assume that type later on. So your code in the Console application becomes:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Specifying int here ...
    UnlimitedGenericArray<int> oArray = new UnlimitedGenericArray<int>(); 
    while(true)
    {
     string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
     int number = int.Parse(userInput);
     // ... therefore we know that the method below requires an int
     oArray.InsertItem(number);
    }
}
```

Comment: No, sir. Like I mentioned above, user can initialize a `UnlimitedGenericArray<string>` or `UnlimitedGenericArray<decimal>` or any type for that matter. There is no room for **assumptions** I have to know the type at runtime and parse according to that.

Answer (score 0):

The only option that comes to mind is to hand the class a method of converting from a known type into in the form of a Type/Func dictionary, like this:

```
public class UnlimitedGenericArray<T>
{
    public IList<T> List { get; set; }

    private IDictionary<Type,Func<object,T>> InserterFuncDict{get;set;}

    public UnlimitedGenericArray(IDictionary<Type,Func<object,T>> inserterDict)
    {
        this.List = new List<T>();

        this.InserterFuncDict = inserterDict;
    }

    public void AddItem(object item)
    {
        var itemType = item.GetType();
        if(itemType == typeof(T))
        {
            this.List.Add((T)item);
        }
        else if(this.InserterFuncDict.ContainsKey(itemType))
        {
            this.List.Add(this.InserterFuncDict[itemType](item));
        }
        else 
        {
            var msg = "I don't know how to convert the value: {0} of type {1} into type {2}!";
            var formatted = string.Format(msg,item,itemType,typeof(T));
            throw new NotSupportedException(formatted);
        }
    }

}
```

Then the usage would look like this:

```
var arr = new UnlimitedGenericArray<int>(new Dictionary<Type,Func<object,int>>()
{
    { typeof(string), v => int.Parse(v.ToString()) }
});

// ok! int == T
arr.AddItem(123); 
// ok, a mapping is provided
arr.AddItem("123"); 
// Error! 
//"I don't know how to convert the value: False of type System.Boolean into type System.Int32!"
arr.AddItem(false);
```

Then if say, you wanted to add boolean support you could change the declaration to:

```
var arr = new UnlimitedGenericArray<int>(new Dictionary<Type,Func<object,int>>()
{
    { typeof(string), v => int.Parse(v.ToString()) }
    { typeof(bool), v => bool.Parse(v.ToString()) }
});
```

Just keep adding to the type convert dictionary as needed.